# Why does toggling off a 1 pixel border create a 75px overflow with a fixed position header and flex grow?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height, border

Perplexed by this...I have the following layout:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      height: 100vh;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    header {
      position: fixed;
      max-width: 800px;
      height: 75px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: beige;
    }
    main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 75px auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid green;
      height: calc(100% - 75px);
    }
    main section {
      background-color: rgb(206, 152, 114);
      flex: 1;
    }
    footer {
      background-color: rgb(245, 186, 36);
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <header>header. position:fixed height:75x</header>
    <main>
      <section>flex grow section</section>
      <footer>footer</footer>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

The border around the body shows it taking  the full viewport height. If I toggle the border off in developer tools, a vertical scrollbar appears and I have what looks like the fixed height of the header below the fold. Even though the block below the fixed header has a margin-top of 75px and has deducted this from its height.

Why would commenting out the 1 pixel border around the body result in this behavior??

https://jsfiddle.net/karasutengu/r8awmpfz/4/

Comment: it's due to margin collpasing, the border is simply disabling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the **fixed** position.

I recommend using a **sticky** `header` instead of a **fixed** `header`. Because your html structure allows it.

In the case of **sticky** positioning, you don't have to set extra margin from the top for the sections, since the sticky element acts as a **relative**.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

header {
    position: sticky;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 75px;
    top: 0;
    /*left: 0;
    right: 0;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: beige;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 800px;
    /*margin: 75px auto 0 auto;*/
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: calc(100% - 75px);
}

main section {
    background-color: rgb(206, 152, 114);
    flex: 1;
}

footer {
    background-color: rgb(245, 186, 36);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>header. position:fixed height:75x</header>
    <main>
        <section>flex grow section</section>
        <footer>footer</footer>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: so the section needed the top margin rather than its containing block. it works, thank you! and I will have to ponder this :) (I did need the fixed position as in the complete code I need the menu on the top to stay put)

Comment: @Kenji, Ok. If you have any questions, please let me know.